# Migrate to Android Studio from Eclipse without Gradle

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

Kinda weird question..

I've been using Eclipse for years, and manually managing project dependancies.

Recently, I've been assigned a project that is built using Android Studio.  It's gone well, but over time I'm finding productivity and project file stability is extremely low.

I'm unfamiliar with Gradle, and without spending at least several days to really learn it just for this one project, it'd really improve productivity time and project build time if I could just remove Gradle entirely from Android Studio.

Is there any way to migrate a project dependent on Gradle in Android Studio such that Gradle is completely removed?  I intended to ask SO about other Gradle processes but I had enough various thoughts that they sort of merged into this one question.

**Edit...**

After comments, here's a simple explanation of my blame on Gradle: the build.gradle file has been changed more than one time by an automated process, and at least once the process's adjustment introduced bugs from extra unmatched closing comments `*/` and extra closing block `}` characters.  I assumed it was Gradle, since gradle adjusts the file system.  Thus, I feel justified blaming Gradle, but I am confident I could wrangle Gradle and Android Studio with some more docs reading. :)

Comment: Is there anything specific from Gradle that you struggle with? Mostly I tend to use it for dependencies and build types, and that's about it on my end. You may need to do more, but know that Android Studio has Google's full support now, and Eclipse has been left behind. It may be best to start familiarizing yourself by learning what you may need to use Gradle for at the moment, instead of learning everything at once.

Comment: Please explain, in detail, how you are planning on building the projects in Android Studio if you "remove Gradle entirely from Android Studio". After all, clearly you have another plan in mind, as that is the only way that you know that your plan is superior to using Gradle. We cannot tell you if your plan will work without knowing your plan.

Comment: @CommonsWare I naturally assume (perhaps incorrectly) that Gradle is only a plugin or add-on to the Android Studio IDE, and as such can be disabled, and its expected contribution to development processes may be performed in a manual way.  This is what I'm basically seeking. I find my project breaks and I get nonsensical error messages when trying to upgrade one dependancy, and if I try to revert the dependancy, other dependancies disappear entirely and a build.gradle module file has been injected with process-breaking characters.

Comment: "I naturally assume (perhaps incorrectly) that Gradle is only a plugin or add-on to the Android Studio IDE" -- Gradle *is* the "manual way". It is not a "plugin or add-on" to Android Studio. It *is* one of a few build systems that IntelliJ IDEA uses, and Android Studio is based upon IDEA. So, it is not out of the question that you can graft something else (e.g., Maven) in there, or somehow manually edit a bunch of not-really-documented IDEA build files. However, you seem to be conflating Android Studio and Gradle; you have yet to demonstrate a problem that is actually Gradle's fault.

Comment: @CommonsWare it should be obvious that I was mistakenly blaming Gradle for something that is clearly Android Studio's fault.  Given the key point of the build.gradle files getting changed, it was a reasonable assumption it was Gradle. Anyway, I'm carrying on. Thanks for the info.

Comment: If you could document the steps necessary to reproduce the problem, someone may be able to point you at what happened that caused your files to get misconfigured. As for stability and productivity, when you used Eclipse were you immediately able to do everything you can maybe do now? Perhaps not. It's just a new tool you'll have to learn. Also, dependency management is a lot better than manually searching for and downloading them

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to migrate a project dependent on Gradle in Android Studio such that Gradle is completely removed?

Perhaps it is but I'd say it's dead end anyway, so do not waste your time. I had good experience in Eclipse times but since it is abandoned by Google and Android Studio is official way to go, I suggest you spend some days getting familiar with Gradle instead of trying to fight it. Trying to sail away from the main course may simply cost you more in longer run.

Comment: I appreciate that.  So far, I've found Gradle counter-intuitive and unstable.  One of the behaviours I found in the last hour before coming to SO was trying to upgrade the Google Play services, then forced to downgrade when new unfound resource errors blew up in my face. Then after downgrading, chunks of my support library v7 are gone, which makes no sense. Also, Gradle added */ and closing } characters to the build.gradle files, which broke the process and left me wanting to throw the laptop out the window.

Comment: @TomPace: "Gradle added */ and closing } characters to the build.gradle files" -- I can see where a bug in Android Studio (e.g., in Project Structure) might have messed up your `build.gradle`. However, Gradle uses `build.gradle` as input, not output. Gradle does not modify `build.gradle`, any more than `make` modifies a `Makefile`. Do you have proof to the contrary?

Comment: @CommonsWare if that is the case, my unfamiliarity with Gradle had me blaming it... Yet if it's a bug in Android Studio, then I really feel ripped apart by this.  My efforts to manage dependancies properly, by hours of Gradle doc learning, are thwarted by processes I cannot identify.  Something definitely did corrupt my module build.gradle file, and rearranged compile directives and comments. And something did delete files my project depended on, during a gradle sync operation.

Comment: @TomPace: "Something definitely did corrupt my module build.gradle file, and rearranged compile directives and comments" -- in a standard Android Studio installation, Android Studio may modify your `build.gradle` file. The Project Structure dialog does this, as will occasional other things (e.g., "do you want to upgrade this project?" dialogs). You, of course, can edit `build.gradle` yourself, and I steer people in this direction. The Project Structure dialog is basically trying to do bi-directional code generation, and that's extremely difficult to get right.

Comment: @TomPace `Something definitely did corrupt my module build.gradle file` I strongly suggest not changing any parameters (i.e. dependencies, sdks etc) using Android Studio UI but open build.gradle file it in its editor for manual modifications - AS messed with my gradle files too many times for me to let it touch it.